# Scala Implicit conversion for Lambdas

Tags: scala, lambda, dotty, scala-3

I am trying to understand the implicit function types from the link - http://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2016/12/07/implicit-function-types.html and below is a sample code as example. In the below code we first create a class Transaction.

```
class Transaction {
  private val log = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String]
  def println(s: String): Unit = log += s

  private var aborted = false
  private var committed = false

  def abort(): Unit = { aborted = true }
  def isAborted = aborted

  def commit(): Unit =
  if (!aborted && !committed) {
     Console.println("******* log ********")
     log.foreach(Console.println)
     committed = true
  }
}
```

Next I define two methods f1 and f2 as shown below

```
def f1(x: Int)(implicit thisTransaction: Transaction): Int = {
  thisTransaction.println(s"first step: $x")
  f2(x + 1)
}
def f2(x: Int)(implicit thisTransaction: Transaction): Int = {
  thisTransaction.println(s"second step: $x")
  x
}
```

Then a method is defined to invoke the functions

```
def transaction[T](op: Transaction => T) = {
  val trans: Transaction = new Transaction
  op(trans)
  trans.commit()
}
```

Below lambda is used to invoke the code

```
transaction {
    implicit thisTransaction =>
      val res = f1(3)
      println(if (thisTransaction.isAborted) "aborted" else s"result: $res")
}
```

My question is if I change the `val trans: Transaction = new Transaction` to `implicit val thisTransaction = new Transaction` and change `op(trans)` to `op` it is not working.

I am not able to understand why even if thisTransaction of type Transaction is present in the scope it is not being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here compiles just fine with dotty 0.4.0-RC1:

```
def transaction[T](op: implicit Transaction => T) = {
  implicit val trans: Transaction = new Transaction
  op
  trans.commit()
}
```

I think it should be clear from the introduction of the blog post that this is a new feature that Odersky invented to eliminate some boilerplate in the implementation of the Dotty compiler, quote:

> For instance in the dotty compiler, almost every function takes an implicit context parameter which defines all elements relating to the current state of the compilation.

This seems to be currently not available in the mainstream versions of Scala.

---

**EDIT**

(answer to follow-up question in the comment)

If I understood the blog post correctly, it is desugared into something like

```
transaction(
  new ImplicitFunction1[Transaction, Unit] {
    def apply(implicit thisTransaction: Transaction): Unit = {
      val res = f1(args.length)(implicit thisTransaction:Transaction) 
      println(if (thisTransaction.isAborted) "aborted" else s"result: $res")
    }
  } 
)
```

the `new ImplicitFunction1[...]{}` is an anonymous local class. The base class `ImplicitFunction1` is this new feature, which is similar to the `Function` for ordinary lambdas, but with `implicit` arguments.

Comment: Can you please let me if  `transaction {
      implicit thisTransaction =>
        val res = f1(3)
        println(if (thisTransaction.isAborted) "aborted" else s"result: $res")
    }` is translated to `transaction {
      anon_lambda( thisTransaction =>
        val res = f1(args.length)(implicit thisTransaction:Transaction)
        println(if (thisTransaction.isAborted) "aborted" else s"result: $res"))
    }  `. Hope my questions is clear

Comment: @jjayadeep Added a probable desugaring of this block into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Implicit function types are planned for a future version of Scala. As far as I know, not even the next version (2.13).

For now, you can only use them in [Dotty](http://dotty.epfl.ch/#getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

`op` is of type `Transaction => T`, not (and I don't think is possible to specify this, unfortunately) `implicit Transaction => T`.

So its argument of type `Transaction` can't be supplied implicitly. It must be an explicit argument. (Only arguments to a function in an argument list marked `implicit` can be supplied implicitly.)

Comment: "and I don't think is possible to specify this, unfortunately" It isn't _yet_.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov "yet" puts a bit too much emphasis on the temporal aspect. Actually, it's *already* implemented, but in a different Scala compiler (for example, it works with dotty 0.4.x).